# clear drop down when input field fill

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to clear my drop down and lock it when I select Input field. Here is my code

```
       <input type="text" class="form-control member-search" placeholder="Search by name" id="member">
       <input type="hidden" name="assigned_to" value="" id="assigned_to">


            <select class="form-control" name="assigned_to" id="drop-down">
            <option value="">Choose team member...</option>
              <% if @m.size >= 1 and !@m.include?("data") %>
                <% @m.each do |l| %>          
                    <% if l["account_user_id"] == session[:user_id] %> 
                      <option value="<%= l["id"] %>" selected><%= l["first"] %> <%= l["last"] %></option>
                    <% else %> 
                      <option value="<%= l["id"] %>"><%= l["first"] %> <%= l["last"] %></option>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </select>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
    <script>
     $('#drop-down').change(function(){
     $('#member').val('');
    });

     $('#member').change(function(){
     $('#drop-down').prop('disabled', true);
     $('#drop-down').val(''); 
    }); 
   </script>
```

with this code these two scenarios happen.

1) When I select input field first and fill it, drop down list become lock. (This is ok)

2) When I select drop down first and then try to fill input field. In this scenario i can fill input field. then drop down become locked. But I have to tap on screen to clear the drop down. i want to clear it when I fill the input field without any action.

I want to disable drop down instead of clear because of below reason.
In here I want to save selected value of drop down to the **assigned_to**

as well as when user fill the input field it also saved in **assigned_to** variable in hidden input field.

It is require to fill only one field. If user fill the input field and do not disable drop down **assigned_to** variable replace with empty value. That's why I want to disable it.

Comment: why don't you disable the dropdown than clearing the items inside? and second, how would you expect to populate the values after it is cleared?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like this:

```js
$('#members').on('change', function() {
  $('#dropdownitems').prop("disabled", true);

});

$('#dropdownitems').on('change', function() {
  $('#members').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdownitems" name="subjectitems">
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">Something</option>
  <option value="2">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="Members" id="members" placeholder="Enter text" />
```

let me know.

Comment: @Dinu, I still feel you don't have to clear the dropdown value instead you can set the value to `0` and use it further not select that value, that will be clean and simple than removing the items.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version based on your requirements, hope its relevant, please note: that I have removed the hidden attribute for checking if it gets populated, you may need to add that!

```js
// set initial
$('#assigned_to').val($('#drop-down').val());

$('#drop-down').change(function() {
  console.log('change', $(this).val());
  $('#member').val('');
  $('#assigned_to').val($(this).val());
});

$('#member').keyup(function() {
  console.log();
  $('#drop-down').prop('disabled', $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control member-search" placeholder="Search by name" id="member">
<input name="assigned_to" value="" id="assigned_to">


<!-- <select class="form-control" name="assigned_to" id="drop-down">
            <option value="">Choose team member...</option>
              <% if @m.size >= 1 and !@m.include?("data") %>
                <% @m.each do |l| %>          
                    <% if l["account_user_id"] == session[:user_id] %> 
                      <option value="<%= l["id"] %>" selected><%= l["first"] %> <%= l["last"] %></option>
                    <% else %> 
                      <option value="<%= l["id"] %>"><%= l["first"] %> <%= l["last"] %></option>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </select> -->
<select name="assigned_to" id="drop-down">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```